# User Input - Data Validation

Tags: c#, winforms, user-input, validation

I'm accepting a string value from the user via a text box in a form. It is then used in a query against a database table and although it is a string, I require the only characters entered to be whole numbers.

I've tried various methods, such as the `INT32` and `TryParse` functions. However, I run into issues when attempting an `IF ELSE` or `TRY CATCH` to prevent anything from executing until the input is 'acceptable'.

What is the easiest way to allow whole numbers only to be entered into the text box, or to identify anything but whole numbers and fail the execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f02979c7.aspx):

```
string selectSql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = @ID";

int id;
if (!int.TryParse(txtID.Text, out id))
    MessageBox.Show("ID must be an integer.");
else
{
    using (var myCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectSql, myCon))
    {
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
        myCon.Open();
        using (var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // do something with the records
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use a [`NumericUpDown` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/729xt55s.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use a NumericUpDown control instead of a TextBox

Comment: The NumericUpDown allows other characters, such as ,.-

Answer (score 1):

I know of 3 possible ways to do it:

1. Remove invalid characters in TextChanged event of your textbox:

   ```
   private void txb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   int selStart = txb.SelectionStart;

   string result = txb.Text;

   // remove all that aren't digits
   result = Regex.Replace(result, @"[^0-9]", string.Empty);

   txb.Text = result;

   // move cursor
   if (selStart > txb.Text.Length)
       txb.Select(txb.Text.Length, 0);
   else txb.Select(selStart, 0);
   }
   ```
2. Extend TextBox control and ignore all invalid keys that user presses

   ```
   public class IntegerTextBox : TextBox
   {
   private Keys[] int_allowed = {
            Keys.D1,
            Keys.D2,
            Keys.D3,
            Keys.D4,
            Keys.D5,
            Keys.D6,
            Keys.D7,
            Keys.D8,
            Keys.D9,
            Keys.D0,
            Keys.NumPad0,
            Keys.NumPad1,
            Keys.NumPad2,
            Keys.NumPad3,
            Keys.NumPad4,
            Keys.NumPad5,
            Keys.NumPad6,
            Keys.NumPad7,
            Keys.NumPad8,
            Keys.NumPad9,
            Keys.Back,
            Keys.Delete,
            Keys.Tab,
            Keys.Enter,
            Keys.Up,
            Keys.Down,
            Keys.Left,
            Keys.Right
       };
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
           {
               base.OnKeyDown(e);
               if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control) return;

               if (!int_allowed.Contains(e.KeyCode))
               {
                   e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. process KeyDown and/or KeyPress event and cancel it if somthing that isn't allowed was pressed

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own class that inherits from TextBox:

```
    public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);

        var key = e.KeyChar + "";
        if (key == "\b")
            return;
        double number;
        string newText = Text.Remove(SelectionStart, SelectionLength).Insert(SelectionStart, key);
        if (newText.Length == 1 && key == "-")
            return;
        if (!double.TryParse(newText, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    public double Value
    {
        get { return Text.Length == 0 ? 0 : double.Parse(Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as another alternative you could use the textboxes TextChanged event.

int.TryParse the text everytime the value is changed, if it doesn't work just clear the textbox (or keep the last value that worked and revert to that on fail).